# How can I make a style event with addEventListener to multiple Nodes

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom-events, typeerror, addeventlistener

I am trying to set a style event for a multiple images tags and I can't: the error is in the anonymous function of the event when I put into a loop to make the effect individually and for all galleries in the document with `images[i]`.

Why ? : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'style' of undefined at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous>`

```js
images = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery img");

for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
    images[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(){ images[i].style=" transform: scale(.8)" }); 
    images[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){ images[i].style=" transform: scale(1.2)" }); 
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/180">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/180">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/180">
</div>
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), it covers similar problem, and all solutions apply to your case too. Easy one line answer: replace `var` with `let`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES6+ solution:

Simply change `var` to `let` in the for loop.

```js
images = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery img");

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    images[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(){ images[i].style=" transform: scale(.8)" }); 
    images[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){ images[i].style=" transform: scale(1.2)" }); 
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/180">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/180">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/180">
  </div>
```

If you must use `var` rather than `let`, you can use .bind() to set the value of i for the function. Otherwise it will reference the last value of i in the loop because of the async nature of the event callback and the higher scope of i due to the use of `var`.

```js
images = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery img");

function callback1(i){ images[i].style=" transform: scale(.8)" };
function callback2(i){images[i].style=" transform: scale(1.2)" };

for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
    images[i].addEventListener('mouseout', callback1.bind(this, i));
    images[i].addEventListener('mouseover', callback2.bind(this, i)); 
}
```

```html
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/180">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/180">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/180">
  </div>
```

Comment: Why would one need to use `var` instead of `let`?

Comment: If you need to support a pre ES6 browser.

Comment: `.bind` is like lambda functions in others languages?

Comment: Ok, but in that case it's probably still better to write modern code and let a transpiler deal with the non-ES6 stuff.

Comment: Bind basically makes a copy of the function that is preloaded with a value of `this` and whatever arguments you want to include. The arrow function `() =>` is more like lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use forEach instead of a for loop:

```js
images.forEach(i=> {
    i.addEventListener('mouseout', function() { i.style=" transform: scale(.8)" });
    i.addEventListener('mouseover', function() { i.style=" transform: scale(1.2)" });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should essentially never use `var` in Javascript but use `let` instead. `var` has weird scoping rules and should be removed from the language, the only reason it's still there is backwards compatibility.

But you should just always use `let` (or `const`) and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `arrow functions` in callback for events to have right context (this)

```js
images = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery img");

images.forEach((img) => {
  img.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    img.style = " transform: scale(.8)";
  });
  img.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    img.style = " transform: scale(1.2)";
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/180">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/180">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/180">
</div>
```